# Get other app's memory class

Tags: android

getMemoryClass() and getLargeMemoryClass() return memory class for the calling application. Is it possible to get memory class of the another running process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`getMemoryClass`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) it says:

> Return the approximate per-application memory class of the current device.

It's the same for any application. It's the memory class *of the current device*.

To detect whether an application is using the large heap option or not, try using [`PackageManager.getApplicationInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). You should be able to read the [`flags`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#flags) field for [`FLAG_LARGE_HEAP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#FLAG_LARGE_HEAP). I think it'll work anyway; the `flags` documentation doesn't include it, but the `FLAG_LARGE_HEAP` doc references `flags`.

Comment: Some apps can declare largeHeap as true, and they will get more memory, then other apps.

Comment: @RankoR right, at which time the same applies for `getLargeMemoryClass`.

Comment: But how can I understand if the app uses Large memory or "normal" ?

Comment: @RankoR Updated my answer to include how to suggest a strategy to detect the large heap flag.